# How to change ubuntu server ip from assigned ranges?

Tags: 16.04, networking, server, ip

Server company assigned some ip's for my dedicated server but i don't know how to change it.Should i change the ip number in /etc/network/interfaces manually? 
my `/etc/network/interfaces` file is like;

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto eno1
iface eno1 inet static
        address 106.***.***.250
        netmask 255.255.255.248
        network 106.***.***.248
        broadcast 106.***.***.255
        gateway 106.***.***.249
        # dns-* options are implemented by the resolvconf package, if installed
        dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8
        dns-search newenglanddns.io
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If no DHCP is running in your datacenter you must do something like:

```
# device: eth0
auto  eth0
iface eth0 inet static
  address   10.20.30.40
  netmask   255.255.255.0
  gateway   10.20.30.1
  dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8
```

Comment: i just edited my post,can i change just ip address on the file?

Comment: @elanozturk yes, you can just change them. But for it to take effect you need to issue either  `ifup eno1`, `/etc/init.d/networking restart`, `systemctl restart networking` or simply reboot.